# Snowflake JOIN with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM
(SELECT * FROM DB.SCHEMA.MODULE_MASTER m
INNER JOIN DB.SCHEMA.MODULEINFO ef ON m."moduleinfoid" = ef."moduleinfoid"
INNER JOIN DB.SCHEMA.MODULE_RETURNINFO r ON m."modulemasterid" = r."modulemasterid"
INNER JOIN DB.SCHEMA.EF_TRANSACTIONS et ON m."transaction_id" = et."transaction_id"
WHERE m."platformtype" = 100 --Desktop
    AND et."firmid" <> 0 --When FirmID exists that means it's pro.
    AND r."processing_status" in (9, 20, 22, 30) -- Rejected Statuses
    AND ef."return_type" not in (1, 5, 7, 11, 18) -- Ignore Extension Types
) as table1 INNER JOIN
    ( -- Didn't have an accepted return later
        select * from DB.SCHEMA.EF_TRANSACTIONS t2
        inner join DB.SCHEMA.MODULE_MASTER mm2 on mm2."transaction_id" = t2."transaction_id"
        inner join DB.SCHEMA.MODULE_RETURNINFO ri2 on ri2."modulemasterid" = mm2."modulemasterid"
        inner join DB.SCHEMA.MODULEINFO mi2 on mi2."moduleinfoid" = mm2."moduleinfoid"
      ) as table2
on table1."moduleinfoid" = table2."moduleinfoid"
```

WHy is this query not working? I've verified each inner query works, but I'm not sure how to correctly alias the outer attributes to do this join. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? Is it erroring - in which case what’s the error message? Does it give the wrong result - in which case what result is it giving and what did you expect it to give?

Comment: The error: "SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'moduleinfoid'"

Answer (score 0):

Your “table” table2 has at least 2 columns named moduleinfoid so the join condition doesn’t know which one to use.

Writing “select * …” is generally a bad practice - you should always explicitly select the columns you need and alias them as appropriate